# How to send array as data to express router from angular?

Tags: angular, express, router

I'm trying to get more details of a number of ID's from the database, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

Here's the array of the items:

```
var memberIds = ["2892056", "2894544", "2894545", "2894548", "2894550", "2894553", "2894555"];
var teamId = '123434';
var categoryId = 6;

// POST  from angular
getMembersDetail(teamId, categoryId, memberIds) {

    let params = teamId + '/' + categoryId;

    return this.http.post(baseURL + 'member-details/' + params, memberIds);
  }
```

I had previously tried GET request with data, but didn't work. I kept getting 404 error from express. So, I tried POST request, but this is also giving me 404 error.

Then in express:

```
router.post('member-details/:teamId/:categoryId', function(req, res){

  const getMemberDetails = async() => {
    try{
      const categoryId = req.params.categoryId;
      const teamId = req.params.teamId;
      const memberIds = req.body;
      const config = {
        header: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      };

      var url = baseUrl + 'member-details/' + teamId + '/' + categoryId + '/';

      const response = await axios.post(url, memberIds, config);

      res.send(respose.data);

    } catch {
      res.status(error.response.status).send(error.response.data);
    };
  }
  getMemberDetails();
});
```

**NOTE**: Express router uses axios to make further post. This is a post to `R` and `Plumber` API. Please disregard this portion. I'm only having problem getting to express router with the data and parameters.

Comment: Check the network and take a look to the route, What is your `baseUrl` ? Are you sure you don't need to add '/' after baseURL ? 
`this.http.post(baseURL + '/member-details/' + params, memberIds);`

Comment: yeah, the baseURL is fine. that's the one I use for other routes and they all work except for this one. I had already add a preceding `/` in the baseURL for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `baseURL` already contains the `\`, then maybe you're missing a `\` in the express router. You may need it before your `member-details` like so,

```
router.post('/member-details/:teamId/:categoryId', function(req, res)
```

notice a `/` in the post url.